# Google sheets script to auto add a new row after every unique value in column A

Tags: google-sheets

Please assist with script for Google sheets to auto add a new row after every unique value in column A

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your goal from `Google sheets to auto add a new row after every unique value in column A`. I apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand about your question, can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will help you

```
const sheetName = 'Tabellenblatt3';

function strAfterUnique(){
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName),
      colARange = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().map(dataRow => dataRow[0]),
      duplicates = [...new Set(colARange.filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) !== index))];

  for (let i=colARange.length-2; i>=0; i--) {
    if (!duplicates.some(value => value === colARange[i]) && colARange[i+1] !=='' ) sheet.insertRowAfter(i+1)    
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it seems to work - Can I take this a step further and get script to only add a new row if there is not a new after after every unique value? The reason for my asking this , is because my sheet is very large - so only adding new row where there isn't any will assist with performance.

Comment: I added a check for an empty cell after a unique cell in the script. Now the script only adds a new row if there is not a new one after every unique value